# $4k$ or $6k$ as remainders when primes divided by primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

While learning basics of programming I made a simple chart of remainders for primes divided by smaller primes. Looks like for every prime $P \ge 11$ there always exists a smaller prime $Q < P$ s.t. when $P$ divided by $Q$ the remainder is a multiple of $4$ or $6$ :   $P=m Q+4k$ or $P=mQ+6k$. If this is true, how can you prove this?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication, this is a Mathematics forum, not a programming forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is true, and a somewhat stronger result is true: you will almost always be able to find a smaller prime which divides the chosen prime and leaves a remainder of either $4$ or $6$. In the rare instances where a remainder of either $4$ or $6$ cannot be found (such as for $31$), there can be found a remainder of $12$, which is a multiple of both $4$ and $6$.

Consider the set of positive integers greater than $1$ having no factor of $2$ or $3$. They are represented as having the form $6k\pm 1$ for $k\ge 1$. Note that the smallest member of this set is the prime number $5$, and all prime numbers other than $2,3$ are included in this set. Note further that this set is closed under multiplication: the product of any two members of the set is another member of the set (i.e. a nmumber lacking any factor of $2$ or $3$), and if a member of the set has factors, its factors are members of the set also (i.e. numbers lacking any factor of $2$ or $3$).

Case A: If you have a prime number of the form $p_k=6k-1 \ge 11$, you can subtract $4$ from it to get a smaller number $6m+1$ where $m=k-1$. Either $6m+1$ is a prime, or it has prime factors. If $6m+1=p_m$ is prime, then $p_k=p_m+4$, and dividing $p_k$ by $p_m$ leaves a remainder of $4$. If $6m+1$ is not prime, then it has at least one smaller prime factor: $6m+1=n\cdot p_m$ and $p_k=n\cdot p_m+4$. But $p_m \ge 5>4$, so here again dividing $p_k$ by $p_m$ leaves a remainder of $4$.

Case B: If you have a prime number of the form $p_k=6k+1 \ge 13$, you will almost always be able to subtract $6$ from it to get a smaller number $6m+1$ where $m=k-1$. Either $6m+1$ is a prime, or it has prime factors. If $6m+1=p_m$ is prime, then $p_m \ge 7$ and $p_k=p_m+6$. Thus dividing $p_k$ by $p_m$ leaves a remainder of $6$. If $6m+1$ is not prime, then it has at least one prime factor: $6m+1=np_m$ and $p_k=np_m+6$. If $p_m \ge 7>6$, then dividing $p_k$ by $p_m$ always leaves a remainder of $6$.

Case C: The rare case for $p_k=6k+1 \ge 13$ (as in Case B), but $6m+1$ only contains factors of $5$, such that $6m+1=5^r$ and $p_k=5^r+6$. Here, dividing $p_k$ by $5$ leaves a remainder of $1$. First, note that a number of the form $6m+1=5^r$ can only be an even power of $5$ if $r$ is even, not odd, i.e. $6m+1=5^{2s}=25^s$. This means $p_k=25^s+6$ which implies that $p_k-12=25^s-6=6n+1$. Either $6n+1$ is a prime, or it has prime factors. If we divide $p_k$ by $6n+1$ if it is a prime, or by any of its prime factors if it is not prime, there will be a remainder of $12$, **provided that** neither $6n+1$ nor all of its prime factors are smaller than $12$. We know that $6n+1$ has no factors of $2$ or $3$, and we can see immediately that $6n+1=25^s-6$ is not evenly divisible by $5$. I will prove that $25^s-6$ is not evenly divisible by $7$ or $11$, which means that any prime factor of $6n+1$ is larger than $12$, so dividing $p_k=(6n+1)+12$ by any of those prime factors will in fact leave a remainder of $12$.

Proof that $25^s-6$ is not evenly divisible by $7$ or $11$: By modular arithmetic, $25^s-6 \equiv 4^s+1 \bmod 7$. As $s$ increases from $1$, the values of $4^s+1 \bmod 7$ cycle: $5,3,2,5,3,2,\dots$. Since division of $25^s-6$ by $7$ always leaves a non-zero remainder, it is never divisible by $7$, and hence has no factors of $7$. Similarly, $25^s-6 \equiv 3^s+5 \bmod 11$. As $s$ increases from $1$, the values of $3^s+5 \bmod 7$ cycle: $8,3,10,9,6,8,3,10,9,6,\dots$. Since division of $25^s-6$ by $11$ always leaves a non-zero remainder, it is never divisible by $11$, and hence has no factors of $11$.

In summary, primes $p_k>11$ of the form $6k-1$ will always admit of a smaller prime that divides $p_k$ leaving a remainder of $4$. Primes $p_k>11$ of the form $6k+1$ will almost always admit of a smaller prime that divides $p_k$ leaving a remainder of $6$, and in the rare cases where that is not true, primes $p_k>11$ of the form $6k+1$ will then admit of a smaller prime that divides $p_k$ leaving a remainder of $12$, which is a multiple of both $4$ and $6$.

Comment: Thanks! Almost clear! As I understand, in Case1 prime factorization of 6m+1 must include even number of factors of type 6t-1. Everything works then if at least one of them is greater than 5. If all of them are 5 we fall into Case4 and have P=6k+1= 6m+1 + 6=5^{2a} + 6. And from this point I definitely missing something: why division of P (of this form 5^{2a} + 6) by some prime Q>5 must leave 4 or 6 as remainder

Comment: You start with $6k \pm 1$ and subtract (as appropriate) either $6$ or $4$ to get another number $6m \pm 1$. If $6m \pm 1$ happens to be a prime, then when you divide $6k \pm 1$ by $6m \pm 1$, it goes in once with a remainder of the number you subtracted, $6$ or $4$. If $6m \pm 1$ is NOT a prime, then by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic if has prime factors, and since the set of numbers we are considering is closed, the factors of $6m \pm 1$ have the same form. (continued in next comment)..

Comment: Let's say one of them is $6n \pm 1$. Then when you divide $6k \pm 1$ by $6n \pm 1$, the part of $6k \pm 1$ contained in $6m \pm 1$ is evenly divided, leaving a remainder of either $6$ or $4$ as above. Except if $6m \pm 1$ only has $5$ among its prime factors, in which circumstance we revert to Case 4 of my answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree with these comments above and agree case1..case3 will work. I just don’t understand the case4 well. Essentially – at the very last row, where P= 3(2k−1)+4, why the number (2k−1) must have a prime factor greater than 3?

Comment: @user1023880 You have brought to my attention a failing in my answer as previously posted. I have rewritten my answer so that it is fully correct, and accounts for those rare instances where a remainder of $4$ or $6$ is truly not possible.